# How to find maximum count of consecutive zeros in column pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe and want to check maximum count of consecutive zero values in Column B.

Example input and output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[1,3,4,0,0,11,1,15,0,0,0,87]})

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'max_count':[3]})
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 11):

One NumPy way -

```
a = df['B'].values
m1 = np.r_[False, a==0, False]
idx = np.flatnonzero(m1[:-1] != m1[1:])
out = (idx[1::2]-idx[::2]).max()
```

Step-by-step run -

```
# Input data as array
In [83]: a
Out[83]: array([ 1,  3,  4,  0,  0, 11,  1, 15,  0,  0,  0, 87])

# Mask of starts and ends for each island of 0s
In [193]: m1
Out[193]: 
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        True,  True,  True, False, False])

# Indices of those starts and ends
In [85]: idx
Out[85]: array([ 3,  5,  8, 11])

# Finally the differencing between starts and ends and max for final o/p
In [86]: out
Out[86]: 3
```

That could be converted to a one-liner :

```
np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0,a==0,0])).reshape(-1,2),axis=1).max()
```

Comment: What is the reason to use `np.r_`? would `m1 = a==0` not suffice?

Comment: @Ehsan To account for any starting 0s

Answer (score 5):

You can create group for consecutive rows

```
# create group for consecutive numbers
df['grp'] = (df['B'] != df['B'].shift()).cumsum()

     B  grp
0    1    1
1    3    2
2    4    3
3    0    4
4    0    4
5   11    5
6    1    6
7   15    7
8    0    8
9    0    8
10   0    8
11  87    9


# check size of groups having 0 value
max_count = df.query("B == 0").groupby('grp').size().max()

print(max_count)
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Idea is create mask with cumulative sum for counter of consecutive values, filter only `0` values, count them by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and get maximum value:

```
s = df['B'].ne(0)

a = s.cumsum()[~s].value_counts().max()
print (a)
3

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'max_count':[a]})
```

**Details**:

```
print (s.cumsum())
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    6
11    7
Name: B, dtype: int32

print (s.cumsum()[~s])
3     3
4     3
8     6
9     6
10    6
Name: B, dtype: int32

print (s.cumsum()[~s].value_counts())
6    3
3    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could adjust it to Python. In Java, you could find most consecutive 0's length using this code:

```
int B [] = {1,3,4,0,0,11,1,15,0,0,0,87}

int max_zeroes = 0;
int zeroes = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    if( B[i] == 0) {
        zeroes += 1;
        if(zeroes > max_zeroes) {
            max_zeroes = zeroes;
        }
    } else {
        zeroes = 0;
    }
}
```

And if you are inclined towards finding the start and end indexes of most consecutive 0s in an array, you could use this logic:

```
int max_zeroes = 0;
int zeroes = 0;
int endIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    if (B[i] == 0) {
        zeroes += 1;
        if (zeroes > max_zeroes) {
            max_zeroes = zeroes;
            endIndex = i;
        }
    } else {
        zeroes = 0;
    }
}

int startIndex = endIndex;
for (int i = endIndex - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if(B[i] == 0) {
        start = i;
    } else {
        i = -1; //used to get out of this for loop.
    }
}

System.out.println("Max zeroes is: " + max_zeroes + " at start index " + start + " and end index: " + endIndex);
```

Maybe you could adjust it to Python.